# How to prove the matrix is a symmetric

Tags: matrix-calculus

What is the gradient of $\theta^T X^TX \theta$ ?

The text book says the gradient is $2\theta^TX^TX$, 
From this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2358321/gradient-of-a-matrix), I got answer $2X^TX \theta$. 
This two answers might be the same, if the matrix is a Symmetric matrix that $2X^TX\theta = 2(\theta^TX^TX)^T$ 
But how do we prove this? Thank you.

Comment: One formula returns a column vector the other a row vector.

Comment: Thanks!! This makes sense.